# Are there IDE tools that analyze and/or display dependency graphs?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, profiling, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm using ninject (though am willing to switch) and was wondering if there were tools that might help me spot "bad" implementations or present visuals of existing dependencies.  The latter would be certainly helpful for design meetings.

Answer (score 1):

[Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) contains [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) which allow analysis on the container configuration. These Diagnostic Services consist of an API that allows you to query this information programmatically (inside an integration test for instance) and it integrates with Visual Studio by showing you this information during debugging.

From the Simple Injector website:

> Diagnostic results are available during debugging in Visual Studio
>   after calling Container.Verify(). Set a breakpoint after the line that
>   calls Verify() and when the breakpoint breaks, hover over the
>   Container instance with the mouse. The debugger context menu will
>   appear for the Container variable which you can unfold to view the
>   diagnostic results. This might look like this:
>
> [image: Diagnostics debugger view context menu]
>
> Another option is to add the container variable to the Visual Studio
>   watch window by right clicking on the variable and selecting 'Add
>   Watch' in the context menu:
>
> [image: Diagnostics debugger view watch window]
>
> The debugger views also allow visualizing your application’s
>   dependency graphs. This can give you a good view of what the end
>   result of your DI configuration is. By drilling into the list of
>   Registrations or Root Registrations, you can select the text
>   visualizer (the magnifying glass icon) on the DependencyGraph property
>   on any of the lister registrations:
>
> [image: Dependency Graph]

Al this information can also be queried at runtime using the Diagnostic API.

[Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Debugger-views&NS=Windsor) contains similar features.